# How i can use "database_sync_to_async" function for fetching multiple object

Tags: django, django-channels, asgi

I am implementing a consumer, and y want get all productos for example:

```py
class MyConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
   async def get_all_producs():
        products = await database_sync_to_async(Products.objects.all)()
```

When i try fetch all products from the above code causes the error "You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async."

I know that query are lazy, but, how i can get all products?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, that is not possible.
Turn your query data into a dictionary and return that.

```
   @database_sync_to_async
   def get_all_producs():
        products = Products.objects.all()
        dic = {}
        for p in products:
             dic[p.pk] = p.data
        return dic
```

Note: You cannot send back the object directly as objects are not JSON serializable.

Comment: I have **class based view**